# Vaadin Maven Spring Boot theme compile

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, vaadin

In My project Vaadin Maven Spring Boot I can't compile theme but the same project in another post work correctly and theme compile easly.Have any idea please?

this is my pom.xml:

```html
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
   <repository>
       <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
       <name>Aspose Java API</name>
       <url>http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>core-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>core-framework</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <type>ejb</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>18.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
   <artifactId>confirmdialog</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
   <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
   <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
    <version>16.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
   <version>7.4.4</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>

 </build>
```

and this is the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8t8I.png)

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to improve the quality of your questions. Add code, pom.xml, log of build, error logs.

Comment: Ok Mr.Steffen , I am changing my post

Comment: Did you define a theme fo your project? Also, from the screebshot it seems you're compiling with an IDE plugin, eclipse, intellij, etc. Are you getting the same error if you try compiling it via maven?

Comment: Yes Ihave a theme in my project.How can I compiling it with maven??

Comment: The [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-compiling.html) is a good place to look for information

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly, you have a Spring Boot project with Vaadin, and you would like to compile a custom theme? If so, please take a look at my [example project on GithHub](https://github.com/ripla/vaadin-spring-widgetset-compile). What it boils down to is that you need to tell the Vaadin plugin to look for the theme under `resources`, not `webapp`.

So given you have the Vaadin plugin configuration in your pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

Make sure you have the configuration

```
            <configuration>
            ...
            <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources
            ...
            </configuration>
```

And the goals

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
```